# Bind forward zone stopped working after upgrade to 9.13.4

Tags: bind

I am running a BIND9 at a network edge. All internal clients query this server, requests should be forwarded to external DNS-servers except if it's for an internal domain. The latter should be forwarded to internal servers. The setup worked fine in the past, but after updating to 9.13.4 I am no longer able to resolve internal names. Previous version (9.12.0 as far as I can see) worked fine. I saw a similar behavior in other setups, so I guess its an incorrect/outdated configuration, however, the examples I found didn't look any different.

The original setup was:

```
options {
    …
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.0/16; 10.0.0.0/8; };
    allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.0/16; 10.0.0.0/8; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-update { none; };

    forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };

    dnssec-validation no;
    …
};

zone "localdomain.int" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders {
                192.168.123.123;
                192.168.123.124;
        };
};
```

With the current bind version, external domains work as expected, if I, however, query hosts on internal domains I get SERVFAIL. The same query from the host bind runs on to the internal servers work, so it's not a connectivity problem. Sadly my distro doesn't really support downgrades, so atm I can't verify when the problem appeared first.

```
# dig test.localdomain.int @127.0.0.1
…
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 38029         
…

# dig test.localdomain.int @192.168.123.123
…
test.localdomain.int. 1200 IN  A       192.168.123.37
…
```

Any idea on what I am missing?

Comment: There's an ongoing troubleshooting session on this issue in the ISC's mailing list that's got to the point of true old-school debugging: https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2018-October/100882.html. There's no solution so far, but removing `forward-only` seems to have some strange effects..

Comment: @PeterZhabin: Should your comment not be the answer to this question?

Comment: I don't think this is the *proper* answer,  it is rather an ugly workaround and information pointer. Personally I think this is related to EDNS0, but I'd rather wait for some clarification on the ISC side..